# What ports/IPs needed for Azure Linux Agent to work?

Tags: azure

I have a Linux VM in Azure IaaS cloud with Azure Linux Agent installed. I would like to restrict all outbound traffic to Internet from the VM except which needed for the agent to keep it working.

What ports/IPs need to be accessible from the VM to keep Azure Linux Agent working?

(When restrict all outbound traffic to the Internet tag I get the error "The VM agent is either unavailable, or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from running.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that Azure Linux Agent makes HTTPS requests to URL like name.blob.core.windows.net to report to the monitoring. The IP of this URL depends on your Azure region - there is a list of [Azure public IP ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653) which can be used for NSG rules creation.

But the number of IPs in some regions like West Europe exceeds Azure limit for NSG rules (200 currently) - so you probably need to contact the support for an increase...